# How do I select an adjacent value from a JSON array using map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some JSON as shown below...

```
var JSONobj =     {
       "headline":{
          "localized":{
             "en_US":"Doctor"
          },
          "preferredLocale":{
             "country":"US",
             "language":"en"
          }
       },
       "identities":[
          {
             "access_token":"AQVUTBfbOs5JLsdfsdfH_W1aZ2N0PrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
             "provider":"linkedin",
             "user_id":"v57678565vf",
             "connection":"linkedin",
             "isSocial":true
          },
          {
             "access_token":"AQVUTBsdfsdfsdfsdfwePrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
             "provider":"facebook",
             "user_id":"hshs8722",
             "connection":"facebook",
             "isSocial":true
          }
       ],
       "name":"John Bob"
    };
```

Using JavaScript I need to go through each item in the "identities" array, find the item with a "connection" value of "facebook", and return the associated "access_token" value.

Note: This example has two items in the "identities" array, but in production there will a dynamic number of items. Sometimes more, sometimes less.

I have been trying to do it using `map()` as shown below, but I can't figure it out.

```
var access_token = JSONobj.identities.map(i=>i.connection);
    
console.log(access_token);
```

Comment: Will there be only one item with facebook, or possibly multiple?

Comment: @Mitya there can be a maximum of one item with "facebook" but, sometimes none at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first object in `identities` that has a `connection` of "facebook", then extract the `access_token` from that object:

```js
var JSONobj = {
  "headline": {
    "localized": {
      "en_US": "Doctor"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
      "country": "US",
      "language": "en"
    }
  },
  "identities": [{
      "access_token": "AQVUTBfbOs5JLsdfsdfH_W1aZ2N0PrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
      "provider": "linkedin",
      "user_id": "v57678565vf",
      "connection": "linkedin",
      "isSocial": true
    },
    {
      "access_token": "AQVUTBsdfsdfsdfsdfwePrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
      "provider": "facebook",
      "user_id": "hshs8722",
      "connection": "facebook",
      "isSocial": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "John Bob"
};

var access_token = JSONobj.identities.find(o => o.connection == 'facebook').access_token;
console.log(access_token);
```

Note (as pointed out by @secan) that if it's possible that there might not be an identity with a `connection` of "facebook", it is safer to use:

```js
(JSONobj.identities.find(i=>i.connection === 'facebook')||{}).access_token;
```

as this will return `undefined` rather than raising an error.

Another alternative in that situation (as pointed out by @pilchard) is to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (although this requires a fairly recent browser for support):

```js
JSONobj.identities.find(i=>i.connection === 'Facebook')?.access_token;
```

Comment: I'd go with `var access_token = (JSONobj.identities.find(i=>i.connection === 'facebook')||{}).access_token;`, just in case `JSONobj.identities.find` returns `undefined`

Comment: @secan good point; I've made a note about it in the answer.

Comment: Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `JSONobj.identities.find(i=>i.connection === 'Facebook')?.access_token;`

Comment: @pilchard another good point :) I've made a note about that too.

Answer (score 0):

create a generala function wich accept identities array and required connection name,
you can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to go through connection array items

```js
function getAccessToken(identitiesArr, connection) {

  let identity = identitiesArr.find(e => e.connection == connection);
  if (identity)
    return identity.access_token;

  return '';
}


var JSONobj = {
  "headline": {
    "localized": {
      "en_US": "Doctor"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
      "country": "US",
      "language": "en"
    }
  },
  "identities": [{
      "access_token": "AQVUTBfbOs5JLsdfsdfH_W1aZ2N0PrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
      "provider": "linkedin",
      "user_id": "v57678565vf",
      "connection": "linkedin",
      "isSocial": true
    },
    {
      "access_token": "AQVUTBsdfsdfsdfsdfwePrbL0LhD5Y5-g",
      "provider": "facebook",
      "user_id": "hshs8722",
      "connection": "facebook",
      "isSocial": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "John Bob"
};

let token = getAccessToken(JSONobj.identities, "facebook");

console.log(token);
```